# Is there a way to add Prometheus monitoring targets and alerts programmatically

Tags: api, monitoring, prometheus

I'm trying to look for a way to add monitoring targets and alerts to Prometheus programmatically via an API like Zabbix.

For example, when my cloud orchestrator software deploys 3 new virtual machines, I will also add them as monitoring targets to Prometheus servers with some pre-defined rules.

In Zabbix, I can add items, templates, graphs etc.. to the server using its API. This way I can automate my cloud infrastructure with monitoring feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a Service Discovery (SD) to control your virtual machines then Prometheus can use that to discover which hosts to scrape. New hosts that are deployed will be added to the SD and Prometheus can discover and scrape them.

Prometheus supports a variety of SD systems like Consul, DNS, EC2, Azure, etc etc.
If you don't use any of the natively supported systems, then you can also you use [file-based service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Cfile_sd_config%3E) and have your cloud orchestrator create and update the config file that's read by Prometheus.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. My cloud orchestrator is OpenStack and the link you gave me has something very interesting. Let me explore more to see if it fits my needs.

Comment: I don't test Oliver's solution yet but as I read through the documentation, It's a way. So I mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Like others have pointed out, Prometheus supports many systems inherently through Service Discovery (SD). For those that aren't directly supported, you can use the file_sd_configs.

**Step 1:** Set file_sd_config to add all nodes mentioned in files in a directory. eg.

prometheus.yaml

```
file_sd_configs:
- files:
  - /etc/prometheus/targets/*.yaml
```

The above settings looks for all yaml files in the given directory and adds the targets mentioned in the file.

**Step 2:** Generate the file

For auto discovery, run a cron job which pulls the node list via API and either updates a file already present or adds files to the directory. The format of the json/yaml file should be as mentioned in the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this

**Option 1:** Use the service discovery mechanism. Prometheus will auto discover dynamically registered service on your service registry ie. Consul

```
- job_name: 'self'
consul_sd_configs:
  - server: 'localhost:8080'
    services: []
```

**Option 2:** Use file_sd_configs in prometheus config

```
    scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'any_job_name'
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - target.json
```

target.json

```
[{
"targets": [ "endpoint1:8080", "endpoint1:8081" ],
"labels": {
  "env": "stage",
  "job": "boot-api"
}}]
```

on file changes prometheus will automatically reread the file, you can also globs to use multiple target files in a directory.